# Import txt file content straight into macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am writing a macro to import data from our database, accessed through a POST request to the URL.

Our API tokens are saved as a .txt-file, with only that token. I don't want to import this token as a SAS dataset, rather I would prefer to import directly into a macro variable.

So, an example:
My file `"U:\API Tokens\example_token.txt"`:

```
D07034E4B64657B295BE96457AE890AF
```

I want to import this into SAS, and assign it to a macro variable `token`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `_null_` to prevent a dataset from being created :

```
data _null_ ;
  infile "/path/to/file" truncover ;
  input ;
  call symputx('TOKEN',_INFILE_) ;
run ;
```